# Linear Support Vector Machine Implementation in MATLAB (from scratch)

Tags: matlab, classification, svm

I am looking for some help on determining the linear decision boundary between two classes.

I've taken a look at the search results with no luck. 
[Implementing a linear, binary SVM (support vector machine)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1757224/implementing-a-linear-binary-svm-support-vector-machine) is similar but not quite on the mark.

My question comes down to how to pull the correct line equation out of the weight vector. 
Given a matrix of test data `X=[Xa Xb]`, where `Xa=[Nx2]` && `Xb=[Nx2]` data samples.
These are in two classes (-1,1) saved in [Nx1] vector `Y=[1 1 ... 1 -1 -1... -1]'`

I use MATLAB's quadprog.m to solve the quadratic program...

I understand that we want to solve `w1x1 + w2x2 + wo=0`, so in my code I solve for `W=[w1 w2]`; and I solve for `wo=1/Y1 - WX1^T`.

When implemented my decision boundary plots as:

[image: decision boundary]

Clearly this is not what I want. The slope of the line looks legit, but I think I want to translate it north a little bit to optimize. In this picture the yellow dots are the support vectors.

It appears that I used the first data point, X(1,:) to be precise, and my line sucks. If I use different points it draws the line in different places, this makes sense algebraically, but how do i get the optimal boundary, not just a parallel boundary orthogonal to the weighting vector?

Thanks!

If you're interested in the code, here it is:

```
function [alph,w,wo,sv]=svm_binary(Class1,Class2)
x1=Class1;
x2=Class2;
% Combine data into one set
xt=[x1;x2];
% Create class labels
y=[ones(length(x1),1); -1.*ones(length(x2),1)];
N=length(xt);
% Scatter plot of original data class data points
figure
scatter(x1(:,1),x1(:,2));
hold on
scatter(x2(:,1),x2(:,2));
legend('Class1','Class2')
xlabel('x1')
ylabel('x2')
title('Class Data Scatter Plot')
% Data component of Langrangian dual
H=(xt*xt').*(y*y');
% Vector to flip signs
f=-ones(N,1);
%Constraint 1) a(i)>=0
A= -eye(N);
a=zeros(N,1);
% Constraint 2) sum[a(i)y(i)]=0
B=[y';zeros(N-1,N)];
b=zeros(N,1);

%Solve Quadratic Programming optimization for alpha
alph=quadprog(H+eye(N)*.001,f,A,a,B,b);
%Solve for W
w=(alph.*y)'*xt;
sv=[];
for i=1:length(xt)
if abs(alph(i))>=.0000001
    sv=[sv i];
end
end
xtsv=xt(sv,:);
wo=1/y(1)-w*xt(1,:)';   
if abs(w(1))<=.000001
y=-wo/w(2).*ones(round(max(xt(:,1))-min(xt(:,1))),1);
x=min(xt(:,2)):(max(xt(:,2))-min(xt(:,2)))/(length(y)-1):max(xt(:,2));
elseif abs(w(2))<=.000001
x=-wo/w(1).*ones(round(max(xt(:,2))-min(xt(:,2))),1);
y=min(xt(:,1)):(max(xt(:,1))-min(xt(:,1)))/(length(x)-1):max(xt(:,1));
else
x=round(min(xt(:,1))):round(max(xt(:,1)))
y=(w(1)/w(2)).*-x-wo/(w(2));
end
sv=[];
for i=1:length(xt)
if abs(alph(i))>=.0000001
    sv=[sv i];
end
end
xtsv=xt(sv,:);
scatter(xtsv(:,1),xtsv(:,2),'fillled','markeredgecolor','black','markerfacecolor','yellow');
% y=-(w(1).*x)-wo
length(x)
length(y)
hold on
plot(x,y)
```

Comment: I believe you need to use a support vector in your formula for computing `wo`, i.e., something like `wo=1/y(sv(1))-w*xt(sv(1),:)';`. Does that help?

Comment: It does help 3lectologos. I'm discovering some interesting things. I'll preface my comments on the fact that I am not an expert in the background optimization and constraint gymnastics. 

I've found that the closer my data sets are together the more SVs are chosen in the optimization, and that the selection of one or another of these SV's to define my decision boundary can greatly affect the placement and overall detection performance. 

Increasing the difference of means reduces # of SV's and improves line placement. 

Perhaps my data is ill fitted for this classification technique.